# No Account For Team "XXXXX". Add a new account in Account Setting - Xcode Signin with Certificate profile

Tags: apple-developer, xcode15

I have a project with a personal account, not my acount, so i try to get certificate from apple developer account
to sign in my project to install on the real Iphone device. i have create 3 cer profile for 3 targets in my Xcode
and also i have the .P12 file to signin keychain. when i using cert it seem good but when i build for my iphone
I get this Error
 No profiles for 'com.huynt.screentranslator' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.huynt.screentranslator'.

No Account for Team "5J9K25GG4G". Add a new account in Accounts settings or verify that your accounts have valid credentials.
[this is how xcode like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pXs3.png)

I try to clean and build folder, and quit xcode, also reset the macbook, but nothing woking, the error still there
I also try to create the cer again, but don't woking too.